# Javascript setAttribute is not working for table element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to set name attribute for those elements using only JavaScript?

I tried setting name attribute for element found inside the each cell of each row. But it is throwing an error like this:

> setAttribute is not a function.

**HTML**

```
 <form action="timesheet_process" > 
<input type="hidden" id="taskcount" value="5">
        <table id="matrix">
            <tr>
                <th>Task Type</th>
                <th>Reference ID</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Efforts</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="sele">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                        <option value="DEV">DEV</option>
                        <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
                        <option value="MAIN">MAINTENANCE</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />
    </form>


**Script:**

    function convert(tableid, temp2){
        var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
        console.log(table.rows.length);
        var hidelement = document.getElementById(temp2);
        hidelement.setAttribute("value", table.rows.length-1);

        for(var i=1; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++){
            var tt = "tt" + i;
                rf = "rf" + i,
                des = "des" + i,
                eff = "eff" + i,
                elemen = table.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0];

            elemen.setAttribute("name", tt);
            elemen = table.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0];
            elemen.setAttribute("name", rf);
            elemen = table.rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0];
            elemen.setAttribute("name", des);
            elemen = table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0];
            elemen.setAttribute("name", eff);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've probably got text nodes in there. You'll have to find the actual element nodes and skip the text nodes.

Comment: @Pointy it's the `getElementById` at the beginning that can't find the element

Comment: @Pointy you where right. I worked on a bad version of his code that had another problem^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is produced, because you do search the element with the id `"taskcount"` (argument temp2):

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />


var hidelement = document.getElementById(temp2);
```

This element does not exist and so it returns null. `setAttribute` will then be called on `null` wich throws an error.

```
hidelement.setAttribute("value", table.rows.length - 1);
```

Without this, your code will run fine:

(to fix it pass the correct id in the onclick event)

---

**EDIT**:

It's a bad idea to use `childNodes[0]`, as it will also contain invisible textNodes. You can use `.querySelector("*")` to get the first node that is a element!

And the loop should be `for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)`

```js
function convert(tableid, temp2) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
  var hidelement = document.getElementById(temp2);
  hidelement.setAttribute("value", table.rows.length - 1);
  
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var tt = "tt" + i;
    var rf = "rf" + i;
    var des = "des" + i;
    var eff = "eff" + i;
    var elemen = table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector("*");
    elemen.setAttribute("name", tt);
    elemen = table.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector("*");
    elemen.setAttribute("name", rf);
    elemen = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector("*");
    elemen.setAttribute("name", des);
    elemen = table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector("*");
    elemen.setAttribute("name", eff);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="timesheet_process">
  <input type="hidden" id="taskcount" value="5">
  <table id="matrix">
    <tr>
      <th>Task Type</th>
      <th>Reference ID</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Efforts</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="sele">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
          <option value="DEV">DEV</option>
          <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
          <option value="MAIN">MAINTENANCE</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Brief your work" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sry , i deleted that part of code from HTML to avoid confusion but forgot to delete from script, now updated the script.I tested code you have given but name attribute is not getting updated for those input element

Comment: @anavaraslamurep ... ... ... well now I fixed that issue

Comment: It's true that it would be an error to call `.setAttribute` on a `null` value, but that would produce `Cannot call method "setAttribute" of null`.  If you're getting `setAttribute is not a function`, that means that you've got an element but it doesn't have a method called "setAttribute".

Comment: @Pointy yes, it produced `Cannot call method "setAttribute" of null` but that was before he changed his question (and now I finaly solved it)

Comment: @CodeiSir It didn't work for me. Still throwing same error, even , if i didn't access any property or method of hidelement

Comment: @anavaraslamurep did you press the "rund code snipped" ? It works fine :(

Comment: @CodeiSir, it worked , sorry i didn't see the change querySelector("*");, queryselector did the magic

Comment: @anavaraslamurep I'm glad it works for you, have a nice day